# How to create a custom TextInput time picker in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, time, timepicker

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0Zt2.png)

Can we create like this time picker in ReactNative.

Is there any other time picker in ReactNative rather than a clock view.

Tried some time pickers like npm i @react-native-community/datetimepicker but everything have a clock view, I dont need clock view instead of the user can or able to type the time there, is there any kind a package available?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.